# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a {(\log(n)})^b}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I used the Cauchy's condensation test and got the series $\frac{1}{(log2)^b}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n(1-a)}}{n^b}$.

When a=1, it follows that the series converges for b>1 (p-series).
How do I deduce the other cases. For example when 0

Answer (score 0):

If $a < 1$, choose $c\in (a,1)$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{c-a}}{(\log n)^b} = \infty$; then there exists $N_0$ such that for any $n\geq N_0$, we have
$$\frac{n^{c-a}}{(\log n)^b} \geq 1\Longrightarrow \frac1{n^a(\log n)^b}\geq \frac1{n^c}.$$
Since $c < 1$, then the serie disconverges.

If $a > 1$, choose $c\in (1,a)$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^{a-c}(\log n)^b} = 0$; then there exists $N_0$ such that for any $n\geq N_0$, we have
$$\frac1{n^{a-c}(\log n)^b} \leq 1\Longrightarrow \frac1{n^a(\log n)^b}\leq \frac1{n^c}.$$
Since $c > 1$, then the serie converges.

If $a =1$. If $b\geq 0$ then $(\log n)^{-b} \geq 1$ if $n\geq 3$ hence the serie disconverges. If $b >0$, consider the function
$$f(x) = \frac1{x (\log x)^b},\quad x\geq 2.$$
The function $f$ is strictly decreasing, then by integral principle, the serie converges iff the integral 
$$\int_2^\infty f(x) dx$$
converges. By changing the variable, we have
$$\int_2^\infty f(x) dx = \int_{\log 2}^\infty \frac1{t^b} dt.$$
The last integral converges iff $b >1$.